# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: An account required by the instruction is missing

Tags: rust, solana

```rust
SolAccountInfo *store_account = &params->ka[0];

uint64_t ref_comission = *store_account->lamports * 0.2;

SolPubkey pk_holder = { .x = { 0x04 ,0x34 ,0x1d ,0xfa ,0xbf ,0xb9 ,0x24 ,0x0d ,0xda ,0x80 ,0x0f ,0xad ,0xd6 ,0x1d ,0xeb ,0xd7 ,0xd1 ,0x3f ,0x74 ,0x00 ,0xa1 ,0xf5 ,0xa3 ,0xe6 ,0xa9 ,0xb0 ,0x5d ,0x32 ,0xdb ,0x51 ,0x67 ,0x03 } };

SolAccountMeta arguments[] = {{store_account->key,true,true}};

uint8_t data[4 + 8];
*(uint32_t*)data = 2;
*(uint64_t *)(data + 4) = ref_comission;

const SolInstruction instruction = {
  &pk_holder, arguments, SOL_ARRAY_SIZE(arguments), data, SOL_ARRAY_SIZE(data)
};

uint64_t res = sol_invoke(&instruction, params->ka, params->ka_num);
```

`pk_holder` is another contract deployed on local network.
when I try to pass `store_account` (owned account) I get that error.

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed:
> Error processing Instruction 1: An account required by the instruction
> is missing

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but are you also passing the account at `pk_holder` to your instruction? You must also pass in the programs that your program calls into. For example, if your program uses `invoke` with a token transfer, then your program's instruction must also take in the token program.